# Create Different AWS Cognito user pools, roles according to tenant with NestJS/Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, nestjs, amazon-cognito

I am developing a multi tenant application using NestJS (Node.js) and react. I am looking to store my users in the AWS Cognito user pool. I need to keep my users in different user pools according to their tenants.And need to create roles according to their tenants. I did not able to find a way to create user pools, roles and users through the Node.js (NestJS) or react. I did not find any helpful way to do that. Can some one advice me how to create different user pools through the program.(Is it possible??)

I followed some tutorials but I am not able to find a proper solution. And authorisation is and authentication looks fine. But I need to keep my users in different user groups according to their tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do this programmatically. AWS Cognito [user pools APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) facilitate this. For an example we can use [`CreateUserPool`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html) endpoint, to create a new user pool.

For `Node.js`, you can rely on AWS [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html), which simplifies the usage of above APIs even more.

You have to use [`CognitoIdentityProviderClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/) and `send` a [`CreateUserPoolCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/createuserpoolcommand.html) with relevant parameters.

Following code block illustrate the high-level approach.

```
//Initiates the client with configs.
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: "REGION"
});

//setup input params for CreateUserPoolCommandInput
const params = {
    PoolName: "the-name-of-the-pool",
    EmailVerificationMessage: "message goes here."
    //add rest of the details as required.
};

//Initiate the command with input parameters.
const command = new CreateUserPoolCommand(params);

//Call send operation on client with command object as input.
const data = await client.send(command);
```

Hope this would help you to achieve your requirement. Please refer given links for more details.